# Getting last typed word in a string variable in Android

Tags: java, android, textwatcher

I need to get the typed words from `textbox` for further use.

So i am using the `TextWatcher` and at `onTextChanged` event i am getting the `edittext` box Content. It gives the full content of the text box.

But i need the typed word not the full content of the `textbox`. 
I need the last typed word in a string variable once the user press the `spacebar`.

My code is here and temptype holding the full content.

```
tt = new TextWatcher() {
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){
                 et.setSelection(s.length());
            }
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s,int start,int count, int after){} 

            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                et.removeTextChangedListener(tt);
                typed = typed + et.getText().toString();
                String temptype;
                temptype = et.getText().toString(); 
                if (temptype == " "){
                    showToast("Word: "+typed);
                }
                et.addTextChangedListener(tt);
            }
        };
        et.addTextChangedListener(tt);
```

Comment: Add your code here... You can get last token form that string, using sub string methods.

Comment: Split String and get last Array Object

Comment: @Top Cat What if i edit the text in middle of a sentence?

Comment: My app is an translitration app, in which i need to send the typed word to the server for translitration. After receiving the translitrated text from the server i want to replace the typed word with this translitrated word.

Comment: The point still remains that if you're given the whole string you obviously have the last one typed; you just have to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int selectionEnd = et.getSelectionEnd();
String text = et.getText().toString();
if (selectionEnd >= 0) {
    // gives you the substring from start to the current cursor
    // position
    text = text.substring(0, selectionEnd);
}
String delimiter = " ";
int lastDelimiterPosition = text.lastIndexOf(delimiter);
String lastWord = lastDelimiterPosition == -1 ? text : 
    text.substring(lastDelimiterPosition + delimiter.length());
// do whatever you need with the lastWord variable
```